# Confused about the optimization constraints since the processes are sequential

Tags: optimization, operations-research

[image]

The solution given in the solution manual of the book is:
[image]

But since the processes are sequential and not concurrent, I believe the inequality should be: $(10+6+8)x_1 + (5+20+10)x2 \le 600$

Can anyone explain why this is wrong?

Comment: I suspect you've misunderstood the meaning of sequential process intended for this problem.  The idea is that for a particular product item (either 1 or 2), process 1 must be completed before proceeding to process 2 (and thence to process 3) to complete the item.  Your hand-drawn presentation of the problem formulation may convey to your Readers that you are not especially motivated.  See [this brief introduction to posting math notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @hardmath That's not my hand-drawn representation lol. That is from the author's official solution manual. Please read the question before closing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that you posted an image from the unidentified author's solution manual, not an image of your own solution.  My suggestions are: (1) cite the text (author and title) of the books which are your sources, (2) explain how you justify your single inequality in place of the three shown in the author's solution, (3) make better use of  `mathjax` to express your ideas.  Using images instead of $\LaTeX$ does put off a substantial fraction of Readers (the images are not searchable or accessible to machine assistive technologies).

Answer (score 4):

The inequality constraint is not correct, since it has a limit of only up to $600$ production minutes per day; the $600$ minutes are allocated for all the three processes.

In the given solution there are not only $600$ productive minutes, but three times that time, because the processes are sequential. There is a constraint separately for each process, each of them are allocated 10 hours.

Comment: Whose constraints? Mine or the author's?

Comment: Author's constraints are assuming there are three simultaneous processes ongoing, but sequentially for each item/product. Your constraint assume there is only one process ongoing at each moment.